# No Cold Water in upstairs bathroon and Kitchen

Tags: plumbing, water, sink

It appears that the cold water has stopped in the kitchen (hot still works) and there is no cold or hot coming from the bathroon sink on that main floor. The bathroom sink in the basement is working fine. I am in Chicago it is very cold here today so I don't know if that's the issue. If its a freeze what should I do? Also should I stop using the basement water as well.

Comment: Sounds like frozen pipes. You should contact a local licensed plumber.

Comment: Where are you located?  There are a lot of questions/answers for frozen pipes.  Did you try anything yet from those answers?